# MMDrawerController with xib

Tags: xib, mmdrawercontroller

I've searched but nothing, well someone has some ideia about how to do it? I will not use storyboards cause they are using sourcetree git and bitbucket and they prefer xib instead of storyboard to do the tasks always, well, I am trapped with xib, any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

```
    var mainController = ViewController(nibName:"MainView", bundle:nil)
    var menuController = MenuViewController(nibName:"MenuViewController", bundle:nil)

    var mainNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainController)

    mainNav.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    mainContainer = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: mainNav, leftDrawerViewController: menuController)
    mainContainer!.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;
    mainContainer!.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureMode.PanningCenterView;
    mainContainer!.setDrawerVisualStateBlock(MMDrawerVisualState.swingingDoorVisualStateBlock()!)

    window?.rootViewController = mainContainer
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
```

Comment: Sry for taking so much time to answer. I forgot to mention that I needed the code in objective. The documentation in swift was good but in obj c was inexistent, thnks anyway and swy again fot not reply in time.